Calculations of generalized Stokes' Theorem on Riemannian manifold
I'm starting to work on some problems which require the evaluations of scalar functions residing on very smooth manifolds. We want to push the calculations onto the boundaries using Stokes', however I'm struggling to make sense  of concrete calculations of generalized Stokes' theorem on curved space. I'm hoping someone can point out where my mistakes are on a greatly simplified problem.
Consider a simple 2D manifold $M$ given by a surface $(x, y, f(x, y))$ where $x^2 + y^2 \le 1$, for ease of parametrization, and $f(x, y) = x^2$, for simplicity. The metric is given by $g = \text{diag}(1 + 4x^2, 1)$. Unfortunately, given even the simplest differential 1-form $\omega = 0 \, dx + x \, dy \implies d\omega = 1 \, dx \wedge dy$, I can't seem to put numbers to the usual Stokes' theorem expressions especially on the boundary.
Performing the the interior integral, we could use polar here, but sticking with Cartesian for now
$$
\int_M d\omega = \int_{-1}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1 - x^2}}^{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} \sqrt{|g|} \, dy dx 
 = \int_{-1}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1 - x^2}}^{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} \sqrt{1 + 4x^2} \, dy dx\approx 4.31 
$$
Numerically, this makes sense as it's slightly bigger than the surface area of a unit circle on flat space.
On the boundary, we use the typical parameterization $r(t) = (\cos(t), \sin(t))$ of the circle, resulting in
$$
\int_{\partial M} \omega = \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{|\gamma|} \omega(r(t))\cdot r'(t) \, dt  = \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{1 + 4\cos^2(t)} \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ \cos(t)\end{bmatrix} \cdot  \begin{bmatrix}-\sin(t) \\ \cos(t)\end{bmatrix} \, dt \approx 6.22.
$$
Oddly, changing the $\omega$ to $\omega = -y \, dx + 0 \, dy$, with $d\omega=1$, results in the correct values on the boundary which greatly confused me.
Is this not a correct application of Stokes' theorem? Any help is appreciated.

Why are you introducing the metric? The integral of $d\omega=dx\wedge dy$ is just the area of the projection onto the $xy$-plane, and in fact does not depend on $f$. Similarly, you are miscomputing the line integral. You need to get rid of these surface area/arclength factors.

Oh, and writing $d\omega = 1$ is just plain wrong. I think you need to restudy differential forms and their integrals. (You might check out some of my YouTube videos, linked in my profile.)

The issue is that I have scalar function $$g(x,y,z)$$ on the 2D manifold embedded in 3D, and integrate on that. At the same time, I know how to integrate the standard differential form $$\omega = \omega_1 , dx \wedge dy + \omega_2 dy \wedge dz + \omega_3 dx \wedge dz$$ on the manifold via pullback.
However, I don't know how to associate a 2-form to my scalar function $g$, and hence I was looking at the Stokes' theorem used in GR (something like https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21280/stokes-theorem-in-gr).

How are you given the surface? If you know, for example, its unit normal at $(x,y,z)$, then we can easily turn $dS$ into a $2$-form without messing with the metric.

The surfaces are given in terms of the the functions, and we can assume the unit normal at any point can be calculated.
So there's a procedure to map the scalar function $g$ to a differential form without messing with all the metrics? That'll be awesome!

That was too vague and unhelpful. Please rewrite and give an explicit example.

A very specific example is simply a submanifold of the unit sphere. In particular, the surface defined by polar angle between $[0, k]$ for some number $k < \pi/2$. Visually, just the "ice cap." The unit normal is the $(x, y, z)$ coordinate.
As for the specific scalar function $g$, it's a large class and numerical but we can assume that it's well defined and $C^\infty$. We can of course just compute $\int_M g$ using multivariate calculus, but we there's a large family of $g$, and computing on just the boundary would be beneficial.

So you have the form $\omega=g(x,y,z)\big(x,dy\wedge dz + y,dz\wedge dx + z,dx\wedge dy) = G(\phi,\theta)\sin\phi,d\phi\wedge d\theta$. The problem is that for arbitrary $g$ this form will not be exact (of the form $d\eta$ for some $\eta$), and so your game plan fails.

I see; it's a matter of mapping $g$ using the $dA$ from, for example, thm $\S 5.6$ of Spivak's.

I'm confused by what you mean by "mapping $g$ using the $dA$", but, yes, that is the formula I had in mind for $dA$.
